# How to debug Unity project with iOS simulator?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

As somebody said, the Unity project must be run on devices, but that is a lot of trouble. Is there any way to run a project in iOS's simulator?

Answer (score 9):

Prerequisites:

- Mac
- XCode
- Unity3D for Mac

Guide:

1. Go to Edit > Player settings > Inspector > iOS tab. Change the **Target SDK** to **Simulator SDK** then build the project again.

   [image: Target SDK]
2. Open **Build Settings** and switch platform to iOS.
3. In the same window set **Run XCode as Debug**, check **Development Build** and **Script Debugging**.
4. Click **Build and Run**, choose a directory for iOS builds (for example, create a new directory named Build.iOS)
5. Build's a long process, take a break.

Unity3D documentation - [Building your Unity game to an iOS device for testing](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-ios-device-testing).

Answer (score 0):

It was supported until Unity3D 3.3. and iOS 4.??? But the current release 3.4 crashes. See this [posting](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/82515-XCode-4-iOS-4.3-Crash-on-iPad-iPhone-simulator-%284.2-or-4.3%29) in Unity3D forum.

Anyway I find it easier to run the project in in editor player for debugging and do real testing on the device. Deploying to iPhone via XCode is always annoyingly slow. So I designed my code to distinguish at startup between device and player like

```
if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) {
    // do what ever you need
} else ...
```

Working with the abstract factory design pattern or singletons makes it pretty easy.